# Associating the Hamiltonian vector field $X_f$ to a function $f$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a complex analytic symplectic variety, i.e. $\omega \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 \Omega_M)$ is a closed holomorphic 2-form, which is everywhere non-degenerate. We can view $\omega$ as an isomorphism $\omega: \Omega_M \to T_M$, and let $\theta \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 T_M)$ be its inverse. Then the Poisson bracket for two functions $f, g \in \mathcal{O}_M$ is defined by
$$\{f, g\} = \theta(d f, dg) = \langle \theta, df \wedge dg \rangle,$$
where $\langle -, - \rangle$ denotes the usual evaluation of a vector and a form. This is a Poisson bracket, i.e. a Lie bracket which satisfies the Leibniz rule for multiplication.
Using this, on can define a vector field $X_f$ associated to $f$ by declaring
$$X_f(g) = \{f, g\}.$$
In *Systèmes Hamiltoniens Complètement Intégrables Associés aux Surfaces K3*, Beauville then claims that the map $f \mapsto X_f$ is a homomorphism of Lie algebras. To check this, I tried to evaluate
$$X_{\{f, g\}}(h) = \theta(d\{f, g\}, d h) = \theta\big(d\theta(d f, d g), d h\big), \tag{$*$} $$
but I don't know how to go on from here.

I get that $\{f, g\} = X_f(g) = \mathcal{L}_{X_f}(g)$, and $[X_f, X_g] = \mathcal{L}_{X_f}(X_g)$, where $\mathcal{L}_{X_f}$ is the Lie derivative with respect to $X_f$. But to conclude $X_{\{f, g\}} = [X_f, X_g]$ we would have to know that $\mathcal{L}_{X_f}$ commutes with the mapping $g \mapsto X_g$.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Vector fields get the lie algebra structure with lie derivative.{g, f} =dg(Xf) =w(Xg, Xf).  The isomorphism of Xf and f is obsious then. Since lie bracket has the same form ( structure) as lie derivative.

Comment: I don't understand this. The Lie algebra structure on the vector fields is given by the commutator, i.e. $[X_f, X_g](h) = X_f(X_g(h)) - X_g(X_f(h))]$, right? Why is that the same as $X_{\{f,g\}}(h)$?

Comment: {g, f} =LXf( g)

Comment: The commutator is the lie derivative..

Comment: Lie derivative LX(g)  with respect to some vector field X of a real function g is just X(g) and this is just dg(X).

Comment: Okay, I get that the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_{X_f}$ computes both $\{f, g\}$ and $[X_f, X_g]$, but why does taking the Lie derivative commute with the map $g \mapsto X_g$?

Comment: { , f} =Lxf both are linear and antnticommutative, satisfy jacoby identity...

Comment: Anyway that's why it's obvious, when you take functions and vectors as operators in the respective algebras. I think that comes from  physics

Comment: But you may as well have asked this in physics stack since this is mathematical physics.

Comment: And mathematicians sadly don't pay too much attention to physics stuff, and physicists don't like to dwell on math "technicalities"

Comment: I think what Ezio is trying to say is that the result is equivalent to the Jacobi identity. We have that $X_f = \lbrace f,\cdot\rbrace$, and so 
$$[X_f, X_g] h = X_f(X_gh) - X_g(X_fh) = \lbrace f,\lbrace g,h\rbrace\rbrace - \lbrace g,\lbrace f,h\rbrace\rbrace = \lbrace h,\lbrace g,f\rbrace\rbrace = \lbrace \lbrace f,g\rbrace,h\rbrace = X_{\lbrace f,g\rbrace}h,$$
using the Jacobi identity in the third equality. Hence $[X_f,X_g] = X_{\lbrace f,g\rbrace}$. This doesn't really prove the result, though, since you still have to prove the Jacobi identity.

Comment: BTW it can be shown that the Jacobi identity is equivalent to $d\omega = 0$.

Comment: But he is talking specifically about lie algebras, so Jacobi identity is a given..

Comment: Even if you felt the need to prove it, you would have the need to prove the magic formula and other tricks u used in your derivation

Comment: But this is what I'm saying yes, just prove jacobi that's it

Comment: The Jacobi identity is not a given, it needs to be proved. The magic formula by contrast is a standard result in differential geometry.

Comment: Read the question. It's about a homomorphism between lie algebras. You can't have a lie algebra without jacobi identity.

Answer (score -1):

For clarity, let's distinguish between $\omega\in\Gamma(\wedge^2T^*_M)$ and $\tilde{\omega}:T_M\to T_M^*$, given by $\tilde{\omega}(X) := \omega(X,\cdot) = i_X\omega$.
From 
\begin{split}
dg(X_f) &= X_f(g) = \lbrace f,g\rbrace = \theta(df,dg)=-\theta(dg,df)\\
&=-\omega(\tilde\omega^{-1}(dg),\tilde\omega^{-1}(df)) = -dg(\tilde\omega^{-1}(df)),
\end{split}
we see that $X_f = -\tilde\omega^{-1}(df)$, or equivalently $i_{X_f}\omega = \omega(X_f,\cdot) =-df$. Since $d\omega=0$, Cartan's magic formula implies $$\mathcal{L}_{X_f}\omega = (di_{X_f}+i_{X_f}d)\omega = d(-df) = 0.$$
Now using the identity $i_{[X,Y]} = [i_X,\mathcal{L}_Y]$, we get
$$
i_{[X_f,X_g]}\omega = [i_{X_f},\mathcal{L}_{X_g}]\omega = -\mathcal{L}_{X_g} (i_{X_f}\omega) = \mathcal{L}_{X_g}(df) = d(\mathcal{L}_{X_g}f) = d\lbrace g,f\rbrace = -d\lbrace f,g\rbrace = i_{X_{\lbrace f,g\rbrace}}\omega.
$$
By non-degeneracy of $\omega$, this implies $[X_f,X_g] = X_{\lbrace f,g\rbrace}$.